# Ubuntu 18.04 2nd Monitor not recognized

Tags: multiple-monitors

Two Dell monitors connected, 1-DVI & 1-HDMI.  The desktop is duplicated to both monitors so I can rule out monitor/cable/power issues.  However, I can not extend my desktop across both displays.  There is no option under settings->display to detect or select a display as shown here:

[image]
For debug purposes, here is my output from xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Here is my `lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
```

Any help or debug steps would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: 
[How to enable integrated GPU (with QSV) on Coffee Lake CPU in Ubuntu 18.x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076441/how-to-enable-integrated-gpu-with-qsv-on-coffee-lake-cpu-in-ubuntu-18-x)

I can now extend my desktop across multiple monitors.  HOWEVER, the desktop display on the 2-HDMI monitor flickers/blackouts constantly.  Again, I know its not the monitor/cable/power because I also share this monitor with a windows machine and do not see the flicker.  I can consistently make the desktop blackout if I move the mouse off the edge of monitor.  I'll keep digging and post any updates as the screen flickering is very annoying.

Any insight is appreciated.